# rating system with voting growing time

Tags: system, rating

I am working in a Multilingual dictionary website, each word in this dictionary will be linked with many human pronunciations, as an audio file that can be recorded by users. Each word can be linked to 10 audio files only, from time to time (ex. After 3 months for each word), the system will delete bad pronunciation audio clips, by using a rating system, in this case (-5, -2, 0 , +2, +5).

But the problem is that:

If one word is linked to:

- (1) old audio file (average quality) with ten +2 votes, and two +5 votes(its rating did not grow as fast as file No. 9)
- (8) old audio file (average quality) with ten +2 votes and one +5 vote (its rating did not grow as fast as file No. 9)
- (9) new audio file (good quality) with five +4 votes (its rating has grown quickly)
- (10) new audio file (bad quality) with one +5 vote (its rating has grown slowly)

That is means, the file No. 9, is good pronunciation file, because its rating has grown quickly, but its score is not very high. How can I use the time growing factor in the rating system?

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can include a memory factor for the votes considering the elapsed time between the time of the vote and now when you calculate the score.

When you do an average, for example with these n=4 numbers is the same to do:

```
 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
 10 / 4 = 2.5
```

than to add the individual contributions:

```
1/4 + 2/4 + 3/4 + 4/4 = 2.5
```

So using this last way of doing the calculation you can multiply each contribution by a memory factor that decreases from 1 to 0 over time making the older values weigh less when adding to the average.

For example a possible factor could be using the 1/x function with x greater than 1.

```
f(time_gone_by) = 1/(1 + time_gone_by)

(time is in days)
```

For a vote 7 days ago it would evaluate to:

```
vote_value/number_of_votes * 1/8.
```

Which is a 12% of the value it would have if the vote had been today.

Perhaps this function is not exaclty the one you need but you can replace the factor calculation with a different function that adapts better to your needs.